# Play with data in a for loop

Tags: php, loops

This isn't critical by any means, but I've got a loop through my users on my website, and i spit out data for each one, something like this

```
for( $i=1; $i<=999; $i++ ){
    $varA = function_a( $i );
    $varB = function_b( $i );
    $myownvar = 0;
    foreach ($varB AS $b) {
        $myownvar = ++$myownvar;
    }
    print($varA.$varB.$myownvar);
}
```

I end up with a result like

- 1 - user_one: (10)
- 2 - user_two: (4)
- 3 - user_three: (9)

I was wondering if there was a 'relatively simple' way to turn the data around in a way similar to what I've got it, but print the data based on the `$this` like this.

- 1 - user_one: (10)
- 3 - user_three: (9)
- 2 - user_two: (4)

Comment: Not with just a for loop. You'd have to build an array of results, sort it, **THEN** display it.

Comment: Well, he could technically create some sort of crazy increment equation that loops in that fashion lol...

Comment: Probably not a good idea fiddling around with the variable `this`

Comment: I consider it very bad practice to call a variable $this. $this is used to refer to the scope of your object in php.

Comment: I appreciate all the downvotes I've received, but it's a valid question. And I'm not using the variable `$this` - i wrote it on the spot. If people are that concerned with it, my actual variable is `$mavars->sections`.

Comment: My question would be, does this pattern continue? Also, something does not add up with the output and your assignment of `function_b($i)` to `$varB`.

Comment: @Shortbus - You did write `$this`. That variable has a special meaning. If you change the name of that variable the question does have a different meaning.

Comment: I know I 'wrote' `$this` - but it's not in my actual code. It's been changed due to the particularity of people and their willingness to downvote based on poorly structured code instead of throwing reasoning at why it's not a good idea or why it's bad without indulging 'only' in minor syntax issues.

Comment: What do you expect from an online community where people can hide behind their keyboards and act superior to others with the anonymity of the Internet and geographic separation - as if they knew everything about all, and anyone who doesn't is simply a waste of breath.

Comment: @Shortbus - Nowt to do with syntax. Try semantics. `this` is different semantically to `myownvar`.

Comment: Syntactically, semantically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not real sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if the pattern remains consistent, then you could do something like the following:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i+=2) {
    echo $i;
    echo $i-1;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
1032547698
```

If you don't want the 0, then you could simply check for it, and discard it.

Since you didn't post all of your code, it's hard for me to give much more than that as an example, but I assume you should be able to see how this would apply to your situation.

Comment: That actually worked pretty well - I'll work my next question with more code, thanks!